# BindingRedirect to different assembly name

Tags: .net, assembly-resolution, assemblybinding

You can use [BindingRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx) to redirect YourAssembly.dll 1.1.0.0 to 1.2.0.0.

Does anyone know if its possible to do this if the assembly names are different.

E.g.

YourAssembly1.dll (v1.1) redirects to YourAssembly2.dll (v2.8)

Answer (score 11):

If I recall correctly, I did this about 4 years ago using the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx). The idea is that you get the AssemblyName request and you return an Assembly. In some cases, I was even able to generate DynamicAssembly at runtime and inject that. I forget what effects strong naming has on this.

Comment: Nice. I call this the binding redirect of shame!

Answer (score 0):

Use ILDASM and ILASM to decompile, modify, and recompile the original assembly so it references YourAssembly2.dll.

I got the idea in my head and did a couple of searches to verify it's possible. See [Is it possible to modify assembly manifests other than by ILDASM/ILASM hacking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546707/is-it-possible-to-modify-assembly-manifests-other-than-by-ildasm-ilasm-hacking) and http://forums.asp.net/t/1582934.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

This should not be possible, due to the fact that your own application has a reference to `YourAssembly1`.

When the runtime loads your application it tries to load an assembly `YourAssembly1.dll` (applying probing and version redirects) and therefore it cannot load the assembly `YourAssembly2` instead.