# Is it possible to modify assembly manifests other than by ILDASM/ILASM hacking?

Tags: .net, manifest

We have a customer who have two .NET assemblies, A and B:

- Assembly A references assembly B.
- Assembly A is unsigned, not obfuscated, no source code is available.
- Assembly B is signed, not obfuscated, there is source code available.

I want to modify assembly A and change the manifest so that instead of referencing a signed version of B, it references an unsigned version.

I know it's possible using ILDASM to dump the IL, edit the references then recreate using ILASM, but is there a better way?

Comment: While you are looking to avoid decompile/recompile I have a post I wrote up a few months ago for this topic.  http://www.hackersbasement.com/csharp/post/2009/09/16/Strong-Name-Unsigned-Assemblies.aspx

Comment: I have looked at writing a tool for this ... but the number of times I have needed to do it was once and the pain in the butt for the parser to automatically edit the IL could be a pain.

Comment: @Matthew - yeah this is a one off, but wondered if someone had built a  something nice with a UI.

Comment: That would be really nice.  This is probably one of those deep, dark edge cases that everyone tries to avoid :o)

Comment: I think the Reflexil add-in for Reflector can do this.  http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/Wikipage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems that decompiling with ILDASM, editing the resulting IL and recompiling with ILASM was the path of least resistance.

Comment: Could you please explain how? I also need it

Comment: Could you please explain how? I also need it